# Installing bath sink draining for pedestal when drain does not line up

Tags: basement, bathtub, sink, p-trap

I have install a pedestal sink in my basement half bath. The drain pipe is perpendicular to the sink and the p-trap does not extend out far enough from the pedestal to allow for connecting. What are possible solutions?

Thanks
Chris

Comment: Please [edit] to add a picture (use the "Sun and Mountains" icon)

Answer (score 1):

More pipe. Either an extender on the trap or extending the drain from the wall.